# es_NI locale not supporting for salesforce

Tags: community, administration, locale

When registering community user for NICARAGUA country **"es_NI"** Locale not supporting, but its supporting **"es"** locale. Why salesforce not supporting this particular locale and how can i solve this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spanish (Nicaragua) (es_NI) will be added as a platform language in Spring 15 (along with ~40 other platform languages). It should be available as a locale as well.

http://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/spring15/release-notes/rn_forcecom_globalization_languages.htm

For future reference, for other locales, submitting to the Idea Exchange is a good way to show demand.

Answer (score 1):

If `es_NI` is not supported, you need to submit a **Case** to salesforce.com and tell them about your problem.

Comment: I don't see it listed on the [supported locales page](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=admin_supported_locales.htm), so probably will need to talk to someone from SFDC to find out why.